# python nosetests equivalent of unittest Testsuite in the test file

Tags: python, nosetests

In nosetests, I know that you can specify which tests you want to run via a nosetests config file as such:

```
[nosetests]
tests=testIWT_AVW.py:testIWT_AVW.tst_bynd1,testIWT_AVW.py:testIWT_AVW.tst_bynd3
```

However, the above just looks messy and becomes harder to maintain when a lot of tests are added, especially without being able to use linebreaks. I found it a lot more convenient to be able to specify which tests I want to run using unittests TestSuite feature. e.g.

```
def custom_suite():

    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    suite.addTest(testIWT_AVW('tst_bynd1'))
    suite.addTest(testIWT_AVW('tst_bynd3'))
    return suite
if __name__=="__main__":

    runner = unittest.TextTestRunner()
    runner.run(custom_suite())
```

Question: How do I specify which tests should be run by nosetests *within* my .py file? 
Thanks.
 P.S. If there is a way to specify tests via a nosetest config file that doesn't force all tests to be written on one line I would be open to it as well, as a second alternative

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure whether you want to run the tests programmatically or from the command line. Either way this should cover both:

```
import itertools

from nose.loader import TestLoader
from nose import run
from nose.suite import LazySuite

paths = ("/path/to/my/project/module_a",
         "/path/to/my/project/module_b",
         "/path/to/my/project/module_c")

def run_my_tests():
    all_tests = ()
    for path in paths:
        all_tests = itertools.chain(all_tests, TestLoader().loadTestsFromDir(path))
    suite = LazySuite(all_tests)
    run(suite=suite)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_my_tests()
```

Note that the [nose.suite.TestLoader](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/loader.html) object has a number of different methods available for loading tests.

You can call the `run_my_tests` method from other code or you can run this from the command line with a python interpreter, rather than through nose. If you have other nose configuration, you may need to pass that in programmatically as well.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm correctly understanding your question, you have several options here:

- you can mark your tests with special nose decorators: `istest` and `nottest`. See [docs](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/testing_tools.html?highlight=istest#nose.tools.istest)
- you can mark tests with [tags](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/attrib.html)
- you can join test cases in [test suites](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/suite.html). I haven't used it by myself, but it seems that you have to override nose's default test discovery to respect your test suites (see [docs](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/core.html#module-nose.core))

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately not. I can accomplish a similar thing by changing the method names from tstXXXX to testXXXX and they would automatically get run by nose. I want to be able to to create custom suites: as it would be a more efficient way to run a certain group of tests and not run a different group of tests.

Comment: Right, thank you. I've added more options, please check if it helps.

Comment: Thanks, the test suite looks promising. If someone can provide a working example that would be grand